# Running a MCMC analysis with a new tree I made using BM, anyone know what this error would mean?

Tags: r

tree_mvBM <- read.nexus("C:/Users/Zach/Desktop/tree_mvBM.tre")

> View(tree_mvBM)

> dat <- data$Tp; names(dat) <- rownames(data)
> Error in data$Tp : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to refer to an object called `data` in your global workspace, presumably a data frame. The object doesn't exist (you forgot to read it in,or you called it something else, or ... ?), so R is instead finding the built-in function `data`.  It is trying to "subset" it (i.e. `$Tp` tells R to extract the element named "Tp"), which is not possible because you can't extract an element of a function. (Functions are called "closures" in R [for technical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).)

This is one reason (probably the main reason) that you shouldn't give your variables names that match the names of built-in R objects (like `I`, `t`, `c`, `data`, `df`, ...). If you had called your data `my_data` instead the error message would be

> Error: object 'my_data' not found

which might be easier to understand.

This is such a common error that there are jokes about it (image search the error message):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm very new to this but glad to know I nailed the sweet spot to be made fun of! :)

Comment: we're making fun of R, not you ...  If the answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.